# Create Table On RunTime in mysql using C# and entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I am working on a task in which I have to create mysql table on button click with existing datasource properties. Below is my code.

Any help on this?

```
public BaseDto CreateTempTable(int dataSourceId, int profileId)
        {
            var dataSourceData = Unit.DataSourceRepository.Find(x => x.DataSourceId == dataSourceId).FirstOrDefault();
            var profileData = Unit.ProfileSettingRepository.Find(x => x.ProfileSettingId == profileId).FirstOrDefault();

            var tableName = dataSourceData.Name +"_"+ profileData.Name;

            var objectType = DynamicTypeBuilder.Createtype(dataSourceData);
            var listType = typeof(List<>);
            var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(objectType);

            AddTableIntempDb(tableName, constructedListType);
            return Success();
        }

        private void AddTableIntempDb(string tableName, Type type)
        {
            //Code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

EF is an ORM, not a database design tool. I can only find statements EF does not support dynamic schema.

There are people finding ways to [work around it](https://www.tpeczek.com/2016/10/entity-framework-6-dynamically-creating.html) though (please note linked blog post is about creating *temporary* tables). Just have in mind your source control will not know about all those tables you dynamically created in production.

If you really want to generate tables on runtime, it's recommended to use ADO.NET.